# On techniques of solving differential equations.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Whenever a differential equation falls under some category
(separable, exact, etc), it's assumed that a certain technique solves it. But what exactly guarantees that this solution is correct apart from plugging in and checking? couldn't a differential equation in principle fall under one category, yet the solution obtained by the trick designed for the family might not work?

Comment: It is a very good idea to check **any** solution as much as possible to guard against any kind of error. Aside from that, do you have any example of a solution that does "not work"?

Comment: No, I just want to make sure that "in principle" the techniques are always right for their respective category of differential equations. That once I identified the differential equation as being separable for instance, the solution obtained be the separation of variablrs technique is always going to be valid.

Comment: Usually the tricks designed for such equations are backed by mathematical proofs.